# c# grouping list of list by index

Tags: c#, group-by

I am from python programming and just a little knowledge of c#. I would like to group the following:

```
    List<List<dynamic>> data = new List<List<dynamic>>();
    data.Add(new List<dynamic> {"a", "z", "m", 4});
    data.Add(new List<dynamic> {"b", "x", "n", 2});
    data.Add(new List<dynamic> {"b", "x", "n", 1});
    data.Add(new List<dynamic> {"c", "y", "n", 3});
    data.Add(new List<dynamic> {"a", "z", "m", 5});
    data.Add(new List<dynamic> {"a", "y", "m", 6});
```

How can I group the list of list above without using keys only by index? I want the output to be:

```
    {
     {"a", "z", "m", {4, 5}},
     {"b", "x", "n", {2, 1}},
     {"c", "y", "n", {3}},
     {"a", "y", "m", {6}}
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure, that you need nested lists instead of some class or structure? Where these data come from?

Comment: Hi dennis, I'm doing Revit Dynamo Node. The data comes from excel and the node of excel in Dynamo return just a 2D array. To lessen iteration (putting the data in class before sorting), I want to group the list immediately. I can do a brute force grouping but for the sake of learning new things, I want to know if there is an easy way to do this.

Comment: Will number of columns be always fixed, or it can vary? I mean, in your sample you want to do grouping using first 3 columns, and values from the 4th column will become group members. Are any other cases possible? Grouping in this particular case is simple: `data .GroupBy(_ => (_[0], _[1], _[2]), _ => _[3]);`, but what if you want to group them in some different way?

Comment: There is a possibility that the number of columns will change but the last entry (the column that will become group) will always be the last column. There will be no other way that we will group them. We just need to group the last entry so we can use other nodes that we have made.

Comment: thank you, I will try your code. again, thank you

Comment: hi dennis, it says cannot convert type for List<IGrouping<(dynamic, dynamic, dynamic), dynamic>> to List<List<dynamic>> .

Comment: Post your code, please.

Comment: the example of my code is the same as written above. a code runs smoothly with the code above then, it will surely run with mine. I cannot disclose the company's code here.

Comment: it worked thank you, just change the parameter definition to var. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Dennis method.

```
var lstOutput=data.GroupBy(_ => (_[0], _[1], _[2]), _ => (_[0],_[1],_[2],_[3]))
            .Select(grp => {
                dynamic first=null;
                first = new List<dynamic>(){
                    grp.Key.Item1,
                    grp.Key.Item2,
                    grp.Key.Item3,
                    grp.ToList().Select(x=>x.Item4).ToList()
                };
                return first;
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, it was solved by Dennis yesterday. It was I that was mistaken. My data type was wrong that is why I encountered error. Thank you by the way, I will try this one too. :)